# What does Flash's soon end-of-life mean for developers?

Tags: flash

In 2017 Adobe announced that Flash will hit End-of-life in 2020. Everybody says that Flash is old already and we should go for WebGL now. Why is it bad that Flash is old and is not updated? How does Flash's end-of-life threatens development of new flash-games? What are the risks of still using Flash over WebGL. I know Flash won't work on Mobile but I target desktops only. Isn't it quite fine for desktops?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air is Flashed based and AS3 programming language that is still growing. you can build Android, iOS, BlackBerry, Window desktop and Mac applications by it.
AS3 is not Script any more, it is real programming language. Also there is a solution to add dll,jar and other native libraries to increase its power!
I know Desktop applications developed by Adobe Air and powered up by C++ code as ane (Adobe Native Extensions) files.

Adobe Air for desktop can build in stand alone versions to. just like old Exe files of Flash.

New update:
It seems that Flash player won't end after 2020 and will be support by a new company!
https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe

Comment: Sure, what about Flash player? I'm interested in Flash as a target platform, not as tools for building for other platforms.

Comment: What do you mean from Target platform? there is still flash players available for some browsers and desktops. but Adobe will end it up by 2020. But just like exe files that Adobe Flash was created before, now it is creating Air exe file to running swf files without need to install any thing.

Comment: So it will it be impossible to download flash player and install it on a browser?

Comment: Say we use the object element to display swf files, will these stop working in 2020?

Comment: I have good news, about 6 months ago, Adobe changed the plan! They gave the Adobe Air and Flash player license to a new company which was related to Samsung named Harman. They said they are going to continue the Flash player releases. https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe